# Updating Spring version 4.2.6 from 3.1.1

Tags: spring

My goal is to update Spring to latest version from 3.1.1 which was compatible to Java 8. 
This was the first time i was trying to update my Spring version from 3.1.1. How to identify the latest stable Spring version release compatible with Java 8.
Can anybody suggest me whether it was the right choice or not, or I need to select a lower version than 4.2.6.release ?..

I tried searching the Spring documentation, as of now the latest stable version was Spring 4.2.6.release stable version as of today.

While update my Spring version using 'pom' it shows following error
Can anybody please provide me with some inputs regarding this ?..
I tried adding all Spring 4.2.6 jars in 'pom' then i got this below error:

```
cannot access org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.
```

Comment: check if you have following dependency in your pom `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-web</artifactId></dependency>`

Comment: Check that you don't have jars with the different Spring version.

Comment: i have this dependency in my pom.xml :  <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
               </dependency>

Comment: @slava :i have different version with spring security in my pom i guess this will impact my latest spring version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience this exception should be caused by the conflict of different versions of Spring dependencies.

Regarding the choice of the version of Spring: considering that you're seeking for a latest stable release it seems to be a right choice.